# Very poor performance modifying lookup

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to create a function that modifies a lookup based on a series of bool values read from the database.

I tried taking an approach like this:

```
IEnumerable<RootDomain> lookup = db.RootDomains;

//bools are nullable
if (conditions.HasCompanyMatch == true) lookup = lookup.Where(x => x.Companies.Any(c => c.CompanyMatches.Count > 1));
if (conditions.HasCompanyMatch == false) lookup = lookup.Where(x => !x.Companies.Any(c => c.CompanyMatches.Count > 1));
if (conditions.HasEmail == true) lookup = lookup.Where(x => x.EmailMessages.Count() > 1);
// etc.. more bool switches

//very slow when it enumerated in any way
var count = lookup.Count();
```

It works but it is EXTREMELY slow.  When the enumerable lookup is enumerated ram usage jumps up to around 800mb and it takes several minutes whereas if I do it all in one step it takes just a few seconds and ram is like 60mb.

I am assuming that doing it like this is adding some recursive queries or something but I am not sure.

What is the right way to achieve this without destroying performance?

Comment: "whereas if I do it all in one step it takes just a few seconds" - can you show the code you used when you did that?

Comment: I mean doing it like `lookup = db.RoodDomains.Where( ... ).Where( ... ).Where( ... )` in one go without any if statements.

Comment: Assuming this is SQL server, have you investigated using the profiling tools to see what SQL is being generated?

Comment: I ran profiler and I can see it seems to be recursively running queries when its updated in the if condition but when i run same query on its own it doesn't do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it evaluating each statement as you chain your conditions?

I think treating your initial lookup as an IQueryable will mean that it should only evaluate when you go to retrieve data (e.g. your count):

```
IQueryable<RootDomain> lookup = db.RootDomains;
```

Comment: YES!  This fixed it.  Thanks